# What's the difference between an SNMP agent and and SNMP adapter

Tags: java, jboss, snmp, mib

I am looking to set up monitoring for a project using SNMP in Java. I've been looking around and I have found some packages: **JBossSNMPAdapter** and **SNMP4J-Agent**. I am not sure what the difference is between these two.

Comment: have you read snmp wiki article ?

Answer (score 1):

SNMP4j-Agent doesn't support JMX by itself, it only helps implement the generic SNMP part of the job. There is an SNMP4j-Agent-JMX package, but it is not free. That may be the most important difference for you.